# update one row of table in the future (Laravel)

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8, updates

the `update` method in Laravel (version 8) edit fields at the execution time, but I want to update fields at a specefic date 
for exemple : 
I have `company` table  with `pack` field : when the customer pay another pack, the `pack` field would be edited after the end of the current pack.

there is a solution for this ?

Comment: Why wait with the update, update the field as soon as someone buys another pack. Or create a second entry for the next pack. But you already have the information, why wait until you save it into the DB? Also what happens if your application crashes?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo I have a logic that if he want to downgrade the pack he can finish the current pack and after that he will be turn to the choosen pack

Comment: My point is, you know now, that you want to do something in the future. So you already have the information. Your DB should be designed in a way, that you can save the information now. I don't know your application, only you can decide, but I would think about it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to setup a cronjob for that purpose, create an artisan command , implement you logic there (the date condition), create a cronjob in the Cpanel. Through the CronJob hit the artisan command ,I think this helps....